# Can I ask a question that I asked in the Engineering stack exchange here, if I don't receive the desired answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

I asked a question on StackExchange:Engineering. It was active for few days. I edited it again, but I didn't get the response after that. Can I ask the theoretical part related to Physics that was used in that again on Physics? Is there anyway I can transfer the question to StackExchange:Physics?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, you can do this. There are two ways to go: first, if the question is off topic on Engineering, you can ask the moderators there to migrate it to Physics, in which case it will be removed from Engineering and sent over to us along with any existing answers and comments.

If it's on topic on Engineering, you can still post a version of the same question here on Physics. There are a few rules to follow when posting a question on multiple sites:

- Don't just copy and paste; instead, rewrite the question to focus on the aspects that are on topic for the site you're posting it on. (You could say that it's not really the *same* question on multiple sites; it's different questions addressing different perspectives on the same underlying issue.)
- If your reposted question would be quite similar to the original, wait a few days for a response to the original before reposting on another site. The idea is that we don't want nearly-identical questions active at the same time on different sites. (The more your repost differs from the original, the less important it is to wait.)
- Whenever you do post a question on more than one site, make sure the repost includes a link to any previous versions of the question on other sites. For example, if you repost a question from Engineering on Physics, the one you post on Physics should include a link to the original question on Engineering. It's also probably a good idea to edit the original question on Engineering to include a link to the new post on Physics, though it's really up to the community at Engineering whether you should do this.

And of course, you should check that the question actually is on topic on the new site and follows relevant policies, as you would with any other question.